# What is needed to create a site map for my asp.net mvc web site that can be crawled by the search engines

Tags: asp.net-mvc, seo, sitemap, robots.txt, mvcsitemapprovider

I have created a web site using asp.net mvc-5 . and I have hosted it to one of the hosting provider and I register the web site with google app.

Now after 1.5 months of publishing the web site online it start to be returned by seach engines mainly google and bing. But the result result will not list my web site links (such as contact, our project, our team, etc). now I read that I need to create a site map for my web site as follow:-

1. From my understanding is that I need to create a `robots.txt`  inside the root of my asp.net mvc and I need to specify the location of the site map as follow:-

> ```
> User-agent: *
> Disallow:
>
> Sitemap: http://mywebsite.com/sitemap
> ```

2. Then I need to create an xml which list my main links.

But I have the following questions:-

1. If I do the above steps , then will search engines be able to understand the site map automatically, or I will have to submite the site map to Google and to bing ?
2. Is there any change that my site map will be returned in the search result without creating a site map ?
   Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Search engines will automatically detect the sitemap if it's in your `robots.txt`. But, I'd recommend creating an account on [Google Webmasters Tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools) and/or [Bing Webmasters Tools](http://www.bing.com/toolbox/webmaster). They provide great information about ranking and you can check if they found an error crawling your sitemap or website.

Also remember that Search Engines really take a little time to start crawling your website frequently, because you don't have their "trust". That will change after some time.